# M2 Confirmation Mail: prefix won't translate

Tags: magento2, template, email, registration, prefix

Customers are saved in the DB with prefix "Mr." or "Mrs.".
Registration Confirmation Email Template looks like this

```
 {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p class="greeting">{{trans "%prefix" prefix=$customer.prefix}} {{trans "%firstname" firstname=$customer.firstname}} {{trans "%lastname," lastname=$customer.lastname}}</p>
 <p>{{trans "You must confirm your %customer_email email before you can sign in (link is only valid once):" customer_email=$customer.email}}</p>

 <table class="button" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

de_DE.csv like this

```
"Mr.","Herr"
"Mrs.","Frau"
```

Rebuild everything, still not translating "Mr." to "Herr"

Any Tipps?

Comment: try to remove  **" "** double quotations, sometimes M2 doesn't work with it.

Comment: i tried that already, but unsuccesfull, sadly